# Why will League of Legends not 'finish downloading'

Tags: league-of-legends, technical-issues

I got in the game after downloading but it says please wait for the game to 'finish downloading' and I've been sitting here waiting for around an hour, but it won't finish. Why is this?

Comment: are you installing it for the first time? most of the time when you patch the game, it downloads the files, then unpacks them and moves them to where they need to go. this process can take longer if you have a slower computer.

Comment: @Dragonrage yes, this is the first time. But I have a 64-bit Windows 10, and it runs really fast. Do you think it might be because my internet is slow?

Comment: it could definitely be the reason. it does have to download quite a bit of files. my client folder is 9.2 GB. generally when i have to download it onto a new computer, i have it run overnight, or when im busy doing something else

Comment: It just said that there wasn't enough storage, so I'm moving it over to a 119 gigs open drive. Lol.

Answer (score -1):

For me whenever a download freezes, which happens to me a ton, I just force close league and it will download again, which shouldn't take long and it won't freeze.